# Java - Defining a Method/function/subroutine within a class method

Tags: java, methods, subroutine

So basically the problem is that I have segment of code that needs to be re-used with very slight variations through out in a java method.

This section of code also needs access to a variable only defined within the class method.

I did a search, but found no way that I can add a subroutine within a method. I thought about adding a local class, but it seems you can't use static methods with these, which is what I really need.

If it helps at all, my goal is to initialise a gameboard, that basically consists of:

```
GameSquare[][] board = new GameSquare[15][15];
```

and for each call:

```
board[a][b] = new GameSquare(params);
```

there should be a corresponding call for:

```
board[b][a] = new GameSquare(params);
board[15-a][15-b] = new GameSquare(params);
board[15-b][15-a] = new GameSquare(params);
```

Ie any special square needs to mirrored across the other four corners.

I'm hoping to have all these included within a single method. If there were a way to have an method within a method, I could just have:

```
method( int a, int b, otherparams passed to GameSquare constructor){
  //initialise those 4 squares.
}
```

But, so far I have not found such a way of doing this.

Cheers.

Comment: If you supply some pseudocode of what it is you're trying to do, you might get better help.  Anything that can be done by a local function can likely be done by an anonymous class, though it won't be as pretty as other languages might give.  Right now I'm not clear on why you need a local method or what it's going to do.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. Can't you write a setter method (like `setCorners` on your "GameBoard" class) that takes a co-ordinate pair and the parameters and sets all the corners. What variations are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's an array, how about just passing the array as a parameter to the method?  Except for primitives (`int`, `float`, etc.), parameters in Java are passed by reference so you are still modifying the same array.

```
method(GameSquare[][] board, int a, int b, otherparams passed to GameSquare constructor){
    board[a][b] = new GameSquare(params)
    board[b][a] = new GameSquare(params)
    board[15-a][15-b] = new GameSquare(params)
    board[15-b][15-a] = new GameSquare(params)
}
```

Using it:

```
GameSquare[][] board = new GameSquare[15][15];
method(board,a,b,params);
```

Comment: Hey that's pretty Handy! It's still a little more verbose than I probably could be if there was such a thing, but that seems about as close as it gets.

Comment: While this will work, it isn't very OOP.   What class has the method?

Comment: I was initially putting the method in the Square, although it might make sense to have a board. That does this instead.

Comment: Also, I've realised that if a method has many local variables declared, things can get very messy =/.

Comment: Yep, it's probably better for code organization if you create a `GameBoard` class to hold the `GameSquare` array, as suggested by user949300.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you need a new class, GameBoard, which contains the array of GameSquares.  It would have a method

setSquare(int a, int b, GameSquare gs)

which knows about the mirroring.

Comment: Yeah you do make a good point. I was just wondering if this was possible though, and this was the problem that got me thinking if java had such a mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

No we can't in Java, which is annoying sometimes.

You can declared the method outside as Kevin shows. It's not that bad.

Local class is also fine. The method doesn't have to be static.

```
final GameSquare[][] board = ...

class Util
    void method(...)
        board[][]...

Util util = new Util();

util.method(...);
```

this is a little more verbose.

Answer (score 0):

is this how you want your special squares to be?

```
class GameSquare {
    GameSquare(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "" + x;
    }
    int x;
}
public class Main {
    void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                if (board[i][j] == null) System.out.print("oops");
                else if (board[i][j].x < 10) System.out.print(board[i][j] + "  ");
                else
                    System.out.print(board[i][j] + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    void makeSpecial(int i,int j,int k) {
        board[i][j] = new GameSquare(k);
        board[j][i] = new GameSquare(k);
        board[n - 1 - i][n - 1 - j] = new GameSquare(k);
        board[n - 1 - j][n - 1 - i] = new GameSquare(k);
        board[i][n - 1 - j] = new GameSquare(k);
        board[n - 1 - j][i] = new GameSquare(k);
        board[n - 1 - i][j] = new GameSquare(k);
        board[j][n - 1 - i] = new GameSquare(k);
    }
    void init() {
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++, k++)
                board[i][j]=new GameSquare(0);
        makeSpecial(2,3,1);
        makeSpecial(5,6,2);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.init();
        main.print();
    }
    final int n = 7;
    GameSquare[][] board = new GameSquare[n][n];
}
```

Comment: Hey Ray

yeah that's basically what I wanted, except, i didn't want to have that huge block of code in between your two nested for loops every time I wanted to initialise a different type of square in a different spot.

Comment: you will need those 8 statements. let me turn it into a function. see the edits. you need this logic somewhere.